# saltstack: how to re-push a key from a salt-minion to a salt-master?

Tags: saltstack

The **short version**: How to get `test.ping` to work, after keys are `-A`dded? And how to re-push a key if you `-D`eleted it from the master?

The **long version**: Steps to reproduce:

- on two RPIs
- install the latest Raspbian on an RPI from the 2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian image
- `aptitude upgrade`
- `aptitude install build-essential python-dev javascript-common libjs-jquery msgpack-python python-async python-crypto python-git python-gitdb python-jinja2 python-m2crypto python-mako python-markupsafe python-pkg-resources python-smmap python-yaml wwwconfig-common`
- add `deb http://debian.saltstack.com/debian wheezy-saltstack main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- install salt 2014.7.0 or thereabouts
- doesn't work
- uninstall it
- `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/saltstack/salt.git`
- `sudo pip install -e ./salt`
- on the minion RPI, edit `/etc/salt/minion` and change `master: salt` to the IP of the master.
- `salt-master -l debug` on one RPI, and `salt-minion -l debug`
- `salt-key -L` shows the minion key. `salt-key -A` to accept it
- `salt --verbose '*' test.ping`. Does nothing
- `salt-key -D` on the master.
- erase the keys from `/etc/salt/pki/minion/...` on the minion
- restart the minion to generate new keys

When I had the factory-compiled salt, test.ping did nothing, and the traffic on SuperUser (and lessor sites) implied I should get the latest version. As usual. So when I did, I decided to try recycling the keys.

Now I can't get the minion's new keys to appear in `salt-key -L`.

The debug tracings from the minion only say happy things like `[DEBUG   ] Attempting to authenticate with the Salt Master at 192.168.0.19 / [DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: /etc/salt/pki/minion/minion.pem`.

The debug tracings from the server only say happy things like `generating master keys`.

Then the minion says `SaltReqTimeoutError: after 60 seconds.`

In online posts about that error, people only answer with the "is the CPU switched on?" style answers. Yes, there's no firewall between the two RPIs. Yes, I can telnet to the correct IP and port. Yes, everyone's running as root, in debug mode.

So what am I missing from my mental model of this situation? If I get the keys to work, test.ping won't work. An entire project is held up, waiting for this one stupid configuration detail...

---

inb4 someone asks for the `salt --versions-report`:

```
           Salt: 2014.7.0-n/a-43c01ef
         Python: 2.7.3 (default, Mar 18 2014, 05:13:23)
         Jinja2: 2.6
       M2Crypto: 0.21.1
 msgpack-python: 0.4.2
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6
        libnacl: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.10
          ioflo: Not Installed
          PyZMQ: 14.3.1
           RAET: Not Installed
            ZMQ: 4.0.4
           Mako: 0.7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Following procedure to reset a minion's key works for me (tested on salt 2015.5.2 up to 2017.7.2):

1. On master, delete current key: `sudo salt-key -d <minion_name>`
2. On minion, restart the service: `sudo systemctl restart salt-minion` (or `sudo service salt-minion restart` on an older, non-systemd OS)
3. Back to master, accept the new key: `sudo salt-key -a <minion_name>`

Comment: unfortunatelly not working for me, 04/2016

Comment: This will work as long as you the minion knows where to look. Make sure that your /etc/hosts file has the salt host name listed with the master's IP (or add the IP directly into the /etc/salt/minion config file).

Answer (score 0):

While the inner question - how to recover after `-D`eleting a key - remains unanswered, the answer to the outer question was, naturally, to re-image the SD card and install Salt version '2014.1.10' from the Aptitude repositories.